# Hibernate not inserting a foreign key value, although providing the related entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 3 relationed classes: ParametrosEntity, NomFicherosEntity and TipoCamposEntity. The problem comes when trying to persist a ParametrosEntity object, providind it with the other two needed objects.

ParametrosEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CON_DPARAMETROS")
public class ParametrosEntity {

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "componenteId", column = @Column(name = "COM_IDENTIFICADOR",
                                                                   nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "clave", column = @Column(name = "PAR_CLAVE",
                                                            nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "fichero", column = @Column(name = "NOM_FICHERO",
                                                              nullable = false))})
private ParametrosPK id;
@Column(name = "PAR_VALOR")
private String valor;
@Column(name = "PAR_LABEL")
private String label;
@Column(name = "PAR_DESCRIPCION")
private String descripcion;
@Column(name = "PAR_PRESENTACION")
private String presentacion;
@Column(name = "PAR_PROGRAMA")
private String programa;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "COM_IDENTIFICADOR", referencedColumnName = "COM_IDENTIFICADOR",
                    nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "NOM_FICHERO", referencedColumnName = "NOM_FICHERO",
                    nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)})
private NombreFicherosEntity fichero;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TIP_TIPO", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private TipoCamposEntity tipo;
```

TipoCamposEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CON_PTIPOCAMPOS")
public class TipoCamposEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "TIP_TIPO")
private String tipo;
@Column(name = "TIP_DESCRIPCION")
private String descripcion;
```

NomFicherosEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CON_DNOMFICHEROS")
public class NombreFicherosEntity {

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "idComponente", column = @Column(name = "COM_IDENTIFICADOR",
                                                                   nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "fichero", column = @Column(name = "NOM_FICHERO",
                                                              nullable = false))})
private NombreFicherosPK id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "COM_IDENTIFICADOR", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ComponentesEntity componente;
```

I have a problem trying to persist a ParametrosEntity object. I assign the data into the object ParametrosEntity, including the needed entities but when inserting I get an error.

Here is the code I use for persist and the error obtained:

Persisting code:

ParametrosEntity param = new ParametrosEntity();

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    ParametrosPK paramPK = new ParametrosPK();

    paramPK.setClave("clave");
    paramPK.setComponenteId("SGACAC");
    paramPK.setFichero("sgacac");

    param.setId(paramPK);

    param.setDescripcion("dfasfasfadfaf");
    param.setLabel("label");

    param.setFichero(buscarNomPorIdyNombre("SGACAC", "sgacac")); //  This obtain an existing NombreFicherosEntity from the DB
    param.setTipo(buscarTipoPorTipo("Texto")); // This obtains an existing TipoCamposEntity from the DB

    session.save(param);

    tx.commit();

    session.close();
```

And the output with error:

```
Hibernate: insert into CON_DPARAMETROS (PAR_DESCRIPCION, PAR_LABEL, PAR_PRESENTACION, PAR_PROGRAMA, PAR_VALOR, PAR_CLAVE, COM_IDENTIFICADOR, NOM_FICHERO) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SGAINSDIST"."CON_DPARAMETROS"."TIP_TIPO")
```

I can see that hibernate is not including the column "TIP_TIPO" in the insert query but I can´t understand why not. ¿What I am doing wrong here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show how do you create object of `TipoCamposEntity`?

Comment: Have you tried like this?:
'@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TIP_TIPO", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private TipoCamposEntity tipo;´